# Maintaining relative positioning of elements after parent element stick to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have 3 elements, and I want them to always be in front of one another as the user scrolls on the page. But when the elements reach the top of the page, they will remain at the top of the page and keep their positions relative with their parent . How can I achieve this with css?

Image explaining my question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BQ8Q.png

I was thinking of something like a parent div that was `sticky`, and it would have 3 children that were `absolute`, but the problem was that while I could manipulate `top`, `down`, ..., to position those 3 elements where I wanted them to be relative to the parent, when the parent hits the top of the page and triggers `position: sticky`, those offset values would also be the threshold value for `sticky`, but I want them to all keep their positions relative to the parent.

Example:

```css
.push {
  height: 600px;
  width: 10px;
}

.parent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute:
  top: 5px;
}

.child3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="push"></div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child3">Child 3</div>
</div>

<div class="push"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From MDN *position* property page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values):

The absolute positioning is explained as:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor.

Later in the same page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning):

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is
> either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's
> anything except static.)

Therefore, absolute-positioned elements placed inside an sticky parent element should be relative to the sticky parent.

I've made a quick snippet using your own code and it seems to be positioned ok according to your picture.

The property **left** or **right** was missing in your code for the absolute positioned children.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;  
}

.parent {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">1</div>
  <div class="child2">2</div>
  <div class="child3">3</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

You can check it on CodePen here: https://codepen.io/agarccav/pen/PoKxVzG